# LibGDX in Manjaro linux : PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

Tags: java, linux, libgdx

I generated a project using gdx-setup on Manjaro linux and when I start the project an error is thrown:

```
ALSA lib ../../pulse/pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

AL lib: (EE) alsa_open_playback: Could not open playback device 'default': Connection refused
[ALSOFT] (EE) Failed to set real-time priority for thread: Operation not allowed (1)
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not locate OpenAL library.
    at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:156)
    at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:102)
    at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:206)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.audio.OpenALLwjglAudio.<init>(OpenALLwjglAudio.java:72)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.createAudio(LwjglApplication.java:282)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:90)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:71)
    at com.mygdx.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:10)
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setVSync(LwjglGraphics.java:643)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:125)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.getAvailableDisplayModes(LinuxDisplay.java:951)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.init(LinuxDisplay.java:738)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:138)
    ... 2 more
```

I did not find a solution to the problem on the Internet. Apparently the problem is that Java cannot connect to ALSA or Pulseaudio

Comment: I think you need to make Pulse Audio accessible by all users on your linux machine, or run your program as sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I think Libgdx and Linux are only compatible when using LWJGL3. So I would recommend using this. Just replace all "LWJGL" with "LWJGL3" in your app.